# Set a default cell/column value in excel

Tags: excel

How can I enter a default cell value if the user does not enter anything?

A time needs to be entered into F17 -> F26. If they don't it needs to say 0:00.
Also if they click the cell and press delete it should also say 0:00. It should never be blank. Is this possible?

Comment: You will need to use vba in a Worksheet_Change Event.

Comment: If you get in a IF formula in F26, which states it should be 0:00 if F17 is empty?